# My ng-table is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ngtable

I'm starting to work with ng-tables, but when I try to load the array, nothing appears on the page.

Appears briefly {{x.Name}} and {{x.Country}}

Any suggestion?

Thank you

**View**

```
<div ng-app="ruyApp" ng-controller="equipasCtrl" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">

<div class="row">

    <table class="table" ng-table="equipasTable" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat= "x in data">   
                <td data-title="'Nome'" >
                    {{x.Nome}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Country'">
                    {{x.Country}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="Equipas/Edit/{{x.EquipaID}}"> Editar</a> |
                    <a href="Equipas/Details/{{x.EquipaID}}"> Detalhes</a> |
                    <a href="Equipas/Delete/{{x.EquipaID}}"> Eliminar</a>                       
                </td>
            </tr>


    </table>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('ruyApp', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('equipasCtrl', function ($scope) {   

$scope.equipas = [{ Nome: "Benfica", Country: "Portugal"},
    { Nome: "Porto", Country: "Portugal" },
    { Nome: "Real Madrid", Country: "Spain" }];


$scope.equipasTable = new NgTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 2
}, {

    total: $scope.equipas.length,
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $scope.data = $scope.equipas.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
        $defer.resolve($scope.data);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: if you want show in `equipas` , try `x in equipas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you are rendering the data in HTML and Script is not correct. Update your code as shown below . [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hvJPDopQfdWhz76NGqEy?p=preview)

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="ruyApp" ng-controller="equipasCtrl" ng-init="init(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))">
  <table ng-table="equipasTable" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'"  sortable="'name'">{{ row.Nome }}</td>
        <td data-title="'Country'"  sortable="'age'">{{ row.Country }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="Equipas/Edit/{{x.EquipaID}}"> Editar</a> |
            <a href="Equipas/Details/{{x.EquipaID}}"> Detalhes</a> |
            <a href="Equipas/Delete/{{x.EquipaID}}"> Eliminar</a>                       
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('ruyApp', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('equipasCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $q, NgTableParams) {
 $scope.equipas = [{
  Nome: "Benfica",
  Country: "Portugal"
 }, {
  Nome: "Porto",
  Country: "Portugal"
 }, {
  Nome: "Real Madrid",
  Country: "Spain"
 }];

 $scope.equipasTable = new NgTableParams({
  page: 1,
  count: 10
 }, {
  total: equipas.length, 
  getData: function($defer, params) {
   $scope.data = equipas.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
   $defer.resolve($scope.data);
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: How can I make the bar appear on the left side with the page selection? I can only see on the right side the bar 10 | 15 | 50 |

Comment: For that you need to override the CSS. I have updated the DEMO link. Please check it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Is not it Vikash. I'm talking about the controls to select the page. Ex: << 1 | 2 | 3 >>

Comment: Ok. You mean the pagination. I have updated my DEMO link and the answer as well please check it. You need to add the total property in the settings. let me know if it works for you

Comment: that's it Vikash :)

Comment: can you include in the demo, the sort and filter funcionality? Thanks

Comment: can you include in the demo, the sort and filter funcionality? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Thanh Tùng pointed out, you just need to change

```
<tr ng-repeat= "x in data">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in equipas">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArtemisYoung/44thogw1/)